# Divergence of the series $\sum x_n$ with terms satisfying $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Divergence of the series $\sum x_n$ with terms satisfying $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

According to my notes, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\frac{1}{n}=1$. So then apply the root test.

I am quite sure that this is wrong, since when taking limits don't we have to conclude that :

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\geq 1$

instead of

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} > 1$?

If this is the case, then I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints/full answers are welcomed as my exam is tomorrow!

Comment: I'm unsure what your Question is asking.  Your "quite sure" comments are correct in noticing that the limit being greater than (or equal to) $1$ is not enough to establish convergence.  Perhaps you were wondering if it is enough to establish *divergence* ?

Comment: Looks divergent to me.

Comment: As an example to consider, if $x_{n} = \frac1n$ then $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}>1-\frac{1}{n}$.  The limit of the ratio is $1$ and the sum is divergent.  But you can adapt this to a proof of divergence in general, knowing $\sum \frac1n \to \infty$

Comment: I apologize for the poor wording. I am looking for a proof that it is divergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all $x_n>0$.

The condition $x_{n+1}/x_n>1-1/n$ is equivalent to
$$nx_{n+1}>(n-1)x_n.$$
Therefore
$$x_2<2x_3<3x_4<\cdots$$
and $x_{n+1}>A/n$ where $A=x_2$. Then the series diverges, by comparison to
$\sum_n 1/n$.